# aws-cdk S3 to CodeCommit deployment

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm implementing a CDK Stack which creates a Bucket, puts files into it and finally creates CodeCommit repository where it stores the files. Everything goes perfect until the new codecommit.CfnRepository is invoked where I get following error:

```
CREATE_FAILED        | AWS::CodeCommit::Repository | CfnRepository
Not Found (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found;
Request ID: 2608A90CD11E9729; S3 Extended Request ID: 1iVrjbDpcwqSrsNc7s/aF
9UpNMg0DGe9ABTAJMuoRkA3f9qSYMqVN0sWeLRdT6ETck/DRx6dDCM=)
```

When I split s3 - creation/deployment and Repository creation into two stack it works, but if it is in one constructor the CDK deployment fails.

Here is my purposed code:

```
export class CdkBeeStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, name: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const myBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'Bucket', {
      bucketName: name,
      removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    });

    new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'DeployFiles', {
      sources: [s3deploy.Source.asset('./lib/Files.zip')],
      destinationBucket: myBucket
    });

    new codecommit.CfnRepository(this, 'CfnRepository' , {
      repositoryName: 'MyFetucinyName',
      code: {
        s3: {
          bucket: name,
          key: 'Files/SourceCode.zip'
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

any idea of how to make it work would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I reckon you want to wait till BucketDeployment is completed, thus try adding dependency like below:

```
    const s3deploy = new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'DeployFiles', {...});

    const ccr = new codecommit.CfnRepository(this, 'CfnRepository' , {...});

    ccr.node.addDependency(s3deploy);
```

But be aware, that as per [aws cdk doco](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-s3-deployment-readme.html)
s3deploy.BucketDeployment extracts the zip archive into the bucket.

Therefore, your "key: 'Files/SourceCode.zip'" needs to reference an unzipped content.
Another option is to reference the directory where your zip file is located and it will be uploaded intact, like so:

```
    new s3deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'DeployFiles', {
      sources:  [s3deploy.Source.asset('./lib')],
      destinationBucket: myBucket
    });
```